# Why Java System.in.read() can call which is not a static method

Tags: java, static-methods, instance-variables, system.in

In java, `java.lang.System` class, which has an **in** static variable.

 Declared as: **public static final InputStream in**

 Which means that **in** is an InputStream varibale.

 However I see some example, using 
`System.in.read()` to read input.

How can it do that, the `read()` method in InputStream is not a static method, how can it be directlly call it? As my understanding, only static method can call directly by a Class without creating an instance.

read() declartion: `public abstract int read() throws IOException`

---

Thank you Jon Skeet for answering, I still have some point don't understand.

If I call `System.in.read()` which mean that I call InputStream class method `read()` ?

```
java.lang.System.in -----> java.io.InputStream ----> read()
```

1. calling `java.lang.System.in` ( which is a static variable), in is a `java.io.InputStream` variable
2. The calling act like calling PrintStream class.
3. The process work like calling : `PrintStream.read()`
4. however I have difficulty on understand the read() method, which is not a static method, as it’s should not be call directly.
5. It should be call like:

   PrintStream rd = new PrintStream();
   int c = rd.read();

as read() should be call by an instance.
read() declartion: public abstract int read() throws IOException

PS: I try this code does not work:

```
InputStream rd = new InputStream();
        int c = rd.read();
        System.out.println(c);
```

But do not know why.

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

Answer (score 7):

> How can it do that, the read() method in InputStream is not a static method, how can it be directlly call it?

You're calling it *on* an instance of `InputStream`, via the static `in` variable. So this:

```
int c = System.in.read();
```

is equivalent to:

```
InputStream stream = System.in;
int c = stream.read();
```

Does that help to make it clearer?

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet for answering, I still have some point don't understand.

Comment: @loadload: Well without specifying what that point is, I don't think I (or anyone else) can help you.

Comment: If I call System.in.read() which mean that I call InputStream class method read() ?
java.lang.System.in -----> java.io.InputStream ----> read()
1.calling java.lang.System.in ( which is a static variable), in is a java.io.InputStream variable
2.The calling act like calling PrintStream class.
3.The process work like calling : PrintStream.read()
4.however I have difficulty on understand the read() method, which is not a static method, as it’s should not be call directly.

Comment: 5.
It should be call like: 

PrintStream rd = new PrintStream(); int c = rd.read();


as read() should be call by an instance. read() declartion: public abstract int read() throws IOException

PS: I try this code does not work:
InputStream rd = new InputStream();
        int c = rd.read();
        System.out.println(c);

But do not know why.

Comment: I edited my question, as in comment I don't know how to format the code.

Comment: @loadload: Your edited question suggests you haven't really read my answer at all. It *doesn't* acts as `InputStream.read()` - it acts as a call to `read()` on the value which has been read from a variable. (You don't "call" a variable - you read it or write it.) And you can't call `new InputStream()` like that because it's an abstract class. These are all fairly basic points - I suspect you should reread whatever book you're learning Java from, as Stack Overflow isn't really good for introducing concepts from scratch.

Comment: @loadload: It's not clear where you got the idea that `PrintStream` is involved, either. `System.in` is of type `InputStream`, not `PrintStream`.

Comment: Jon Skeet, Thank you so much for your explanation, I need sometime to digest it and I will reread the textbook. Again, thanks a lot.